# Golang - Calling function defined from macro using cgo

Tags: c, go, cgo

I have been working in Golang and using cgo to call C functions. Im trying to import a macro but im getting error

> could not determine kind of name for C.API_ADD2CONNS

Here is the C macro im trying to use that is defined in c file :

```
#define API_ADD2CONNS(conb, fib1, fib2) do { \
if ((conb)->length < API_MAXFIBRES) {\
    (conb)->list[(conb)->length].fibre1 = fib1;\
    (conb)->list[(conb)->length].fibre2 = fib2;\
    (conb)->length++;\
}\
else \
    log_err("Too many conns! Max %d in API", API_MAXFIBRES);\
} while (0)
```

Call in go file looks like this :

```
C.API_ADD2CONNS(&OxcCStruct,C.int(fib1),C.int(fib2))
```

I have imported headers correctly since i can make other functions work correctly.

Comment: The macros is just a search and replace that's done pre compile time. I'm not sure you can import any macro at all.

Comment: It is not a function.You cant "call" macro.

Comment: 1.compile your .c file to build lib.
2.when you get xx.h and the lib.
3. use golang to call the function.